# iPhone 5 screen is black in my app but works fine on others, no error messages logged

Tags: ios, iphone

I am just starting to work on a large new code base, so I understand that folks' reaction might be 'show me the code' but I can't do that just yet. What I know is that when I use the 'camera view' for this app on the iPhone 5, it loads a camera view fine except that I've got a black screen (the flash and camera flip and cancel buttons are all there as desired). On the other hand, if I run this on the iPhone 6, it runs fine. Both have recently updated OS and the same version of the app.

Is this a known bug of any kind? Any ideas where I should start looking? An internet search didn't turn up anything like this.

Comment: So the screen isn't black. The only problem is you can see the view from the camera on the iPhone 5, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea. Check the Camera Privacy permissions.

Go to Settings app => Privacy => Camera and allow the permissions if denied.

Just tested on my own app where I used pure `UIImagePickerViewController`. Not allowing the app to use the camera results in black screen, exactly as you explained.

[image]